# Unsummon a summoned creature in Dungeon Siege 2?

Tags: dungeon-siege-2

Is there a way to "unsummon" a summoned creature? It appears there isn't, at least from my fruitless Google searching.  Would be nice to not have to wait for the summon time to run out.

Comment: why do you wish to unsummon the creature?

Comment: Say I have a summoned creature and then find a better spell?  Yeah, I can wait for the old one to expire, but why should I... well, if there's a way to get rid of the old, that is.

Comment: I recommend adding that information to your question @jae :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently picked up the game after I played the first one a few years ago.
You can "unsummon" a summoned creature by using the [Summon Teleporter](http://ds.heavengames.com/library/ds2/spells/index_html?spellid=208) spell. In a few seconds time you're back and forth, so that's better than waiting till the timer runs out. Just be sure that you don't have the old creature on autocast :)

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm about 5 years too late, but I know the answer to this!

You can desummon a summoned creature by canceling the associated buff. There are two methods to cancel a buff.

Method 1:
On top top left, on the party member UI, there will be a portrait surrounded by small icons for every effect currently on the player. Friendly buffs can be canceled by right-clicking the buff icon for the buff you wish to cancel.
http://screencloud.net/v/r5x5

Method 2:
In the inventory screen, there is a button labeled [view]. If you click this button, you will be shown a rendering of your character. In addition, this small window that pops up will have graphical icons for every buff currently effecting your character. As in method 1, you can right-click these buffs to cancel them.
http://screencloud.net/v/l6E1

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that casting another summon will unsummon the first one, although it's been a long while since I played some DS2. Cracking title, might have to pick it up again.

Comment: you do that, and the game goes "You can only have one creature summoned" at you